# Entity Framework - Fill with data from database

Tags: c#, sql, database, entity-framework-6

I am trying to fill an adjacency matrix from data from my database but I'm completely lost.

I know how to do it normally but not with Entity Framework.

[This is the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpLGV.png)
As you can see for example on the first line, `IdNodoInicial-IdNodoFinal` is 1->2.

How could I go about doing this when querying the data?

```
foreach (int x in MatrizAdyacencia)
{
    int ini = Convert.ToInt32(grafosdb.Aristas.Select(y => y.IdNodoInicial).ToString())-1;
    int fin = Convert.ToInt32(grafosdb.Aristas.Select(y => y.idNodoFinal).ToString())-1;

    MatrizAdyacencia[ini,fin]= Convert.ToInt32(grafosdb.Aristas.Select(y => y.Costo));
    MatrizAdyacencia[fin,ini] = Convert.ToInt32(grafosdb.Aristas.Select(y => y.Costo));
}
```

This is what I have so far and I'm getting this error

> System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

Comment: You are trying to convert a query result into Int32 (here is the line of code grafosdb.Aristas.Select(y => y.Costo)). I would say try to use.First() instead of .Select() and see if it removes that error. Let me know if it worked out for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are looping through the matrix. I would loop through the rows of data and do your matrix stuff in there:

```
// grab the rows you want, this would be all
var aristaList = grafosdb.Aristas.ToList();  // unless Aristas is a List from Repo?

foreach (var arista in aristaList)
{
    // not exactly sure what you are dong here, but equivalent would be
    int ini = Convert.ToInt32(arista.IdNodoInicial)-1;
    int fin = Convert.ToInt32(arista.idNodoFinal)-1;

    // populate matrix (assuming it was initialized)
    MatrizAdyacencia[ini,fin] = Convert.ToInt32(arista.Costo);
    MatrizAdyacencia[fin,ini] = Convert.ToInt32(arista.Costo);

}
```

Comment: This works, I got so into my assignment that I forgot to comment back. Thank you